# App is crashing when I use TextBlock styles BodyTextBlockStyle and BodyStrongTextBlockStyle in uwp app

Tags: xaml, uwp, winrt-xaml, uwp-xaml

I am developing a UWP app and trying to use styles `BodyTextBlockStyle` and `BodyStrongTextBlockStyle`. But as soon as I use these styles on `TextBlock`, app is crashing with following callstack. I see that these styles are standard ones (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/apps/design/style/xaml-theme-resources) so I assume I do not need to add any references to the project. But if that is the case, can you please guide me which one to add and how?

Please help.

```
    KernelBase.dll!00007ff86c1efe7c()   Unknown No symbols loaded.
    vcruntime140d_app.dll!00007ff85608b460()    Unknown No symbols loaded.
>   FamilyValueProp.dll!winrt::throw_hresult({...}) Line 4781   C++ Symbols loaded.
    FamilyValueProp.dll!winrt::check_hresult({...}) Line 4827   C++ Symbols loaded.
    FamilyValueProp.dll!winrt::impl::consume_Windows_UI_Xaml_IApplicationStatics<winrt::Windows::UI::Xaml::IApplicationStatics>::LoadComponent({...}, {...}, Nested) Line 266   C++ Symbols loaded.
    FamilyValueProp.dll!winrt::Windows::UI::Xaml::Application::LoadComponent::__l2::<lambda>({...}) Line 12248  C++ Symbols loaded.
    FamilyValueProp.dll!winrt::impl::factory_cache_entry<winrt::Windows::UI::Xaml::Application,winrt::Windows::UI::Xaml::IApplicationStatics>::call<void <lambda>(const winrt::Windows::UI::Xaml::IApplicationStatics &) &>(void <lambda>(const winrt::Windows::UI::Xaml::IApplicationStatics & f){...}) Line 6084  C++ Symbols loaded.
    FamilyValueProp.dll!winrt::impl::call_factory<winrt::Windows::UI::Xaml::Application,winrt::Windows::UI::Xaml::IApplicationStatics,void <lambda>(const winrt::Windows::UI::Xaml::IApplicationStatics &)>(void <lambda>(const winrt::Windows::UI::Xaml::IApplicationStatics & f){...}) Line 6107  C++ Symbols loaded.
    FamilyValueProp.dll!winrt::Windows::UI::Xaml::Application::LoadComponent({...}, {...}, Nested) Line 12249   C++ Symbols loaded.
    FamilyValueProp.dll!winrt::FamilyValueProp::implementation::FamilyValuePropControlT<winrt::FamilyValueProp::implementation::FamilyValuePropControl>::InitializeComponent() Line 31  C++ Symbols loaded.
    FamilyValueProp.dll!winrt::FamilyValueProp::implementation::FamilyValuePropControl::FamilyValuePropControl() Line 16    C++ Symbols loaded.
    FamilyValueProp.dll!winrt::impl::heap_implements<winrt::FamilyValueProp::implementation::FamilyValuePropControl>::heap_implements<winrt::FamilyValueProp::implementation::FamilyValuePropControl>() C++ Symbols loaded.
    FamilyValueProp.dll!winrt::make<winrt::FamilyValueProp::implementation::FamilyValuePropControl>() Line 7552 C++ Symbols loaded.
    FamilyValueProp.dll!winrt::FamilyValueProp::factory_implementation::FamilyValuePropControlT<winrt::FamilyValueProp::factory_implementation::FamilyValuePropControl,winrt::FamilyValueProp::implementation::FamilyValuePropControl>::ActivateInstance() Line 44  C++ Symbols loaded.
    FamilyValueProp.dll!winrt::impl::produce<winrt::FamilyValueProp::factory_implementation::FamilyValuePropControl,winrt::Windows::Foundation::IActivationFactory>::ActivateInstance(0x000000784f3fc3e0) Line 6153 C++ Symbols loaded.
    combase.dll!00007ff86d7d5f9d()  Unknown No symbols loaded.
    combase.dll!00007ff86d7d59f1()  Unknown No symbols loaded.
    windowsudk.shellcommon.dll!00007ff8542cc280()   Unknown No symbols loaded.
    windowsudk.shellcommon.dll!00007ff8542cc075()   Unknown No symbols loaded.
    FamilyValuePropTestApp.exe!winrt::impl::consume_WindowsUdk_ApplicationModel_AppExtensions_IXamlExtensions<winrt::WindowsUdk::ApplicationModel::AppExtensions::IXamlExtensions>::GetInstanceFromExtension({...}, {...}) Line 180 C++ Symbols loaded.
    FamilyValuePropTestApp.exe!winrt::FamilyValuePropTestApp::implementation::MainPage::MainPage() Line 32  C++ Symbols loaded.
    FamilyValuePropTestApp.exe!winrt::impl::heap_implements<winrt::FamilyValuePropTestApp::implementation::MainPage>::heap_implements<winrt::FamilyValuePropTestApp::implementation::MainPage>()    C++ Symbols loaded.
    FamilyValuePropTestApp.exe!winrt::make<winrt::FamilyValuePropTestApp::implementation::MainPage>() Line 7552 C++ Symbols loaded.
    FamilyValuePropTestApp.exe!winrt::FamilyValuePropTestApp::implementation::ActivateLocalType<winrt::FamilyValuePropTestApp::implementation::MainPage>() Line 35  C++ Symbols loaded.
    FamilyValuePropTestApp.exe!winrt::FamilyValuePropTestApp::implementation::XamlUserType::ActivateInstance() Line 452 C++ Symbols loaded.
    FamilyValuePropTestApp.exe!winrt::impl::produce<winrt::FamilyValuePropTestApp::implementation::XamlUserType,winrt::Windows::UI::Xaml::Markup::IXamlType>::ActivateInstance(0x000000784f3fcfe0) Line 863 C++ Symbols loaded.
    Windows.UI.Xaml.dll!00007ff8591f5592()  Unknown No symbols loaded.
    Windows.UI.Xaml.dll!00007ff859167afc()  Unknown No symbols loaded.
    Windows.UI.Xaml.dll!00007ff859166eae()  Unknown No symbols loaded.
    Windows.UI.Xaml.dll!00007ff859166d25()  Unknown No symbols loaded.
    Windows.UI.Xaml.dll!00007ff859166c39()  Unknown No symbols loaded.
    Windows.UI.Xaml.dll!00007ff859166baf()  Unknown No symbols loaded.
    Windows.UI.Xaml.dll!00007ff859166a38()  Unknown No symbols loaded.
    Windows.UI.Xaml.dll!00007ff85916690f()  Unknown No symbols loaded.
    FamilyValuePropTestApp.exe!winrt::impl::consume_Windows_UI_Xaml_Controls_IFrame<winrt::Windows::UI::Xaml::Controls::IFrame>::Navigate({...}, {...}) Line 6167   C++ Symbols loaded.
    FamilyValuePropTestApp.exe!winrt::FamilyValuePropTestApp::implementation::App::OnLaunched({...}) Line 83    C++ Symbols loaded.
    FamilyValuePropTestApp.exe!winrt::impl::produce<winrt::FamilyValuePropTestApp::implementation::App,winrt::Windows::UI::Xaml::IApplicationOverrides>::OnLaunched(0x000001b502c44130) Line 5047   C++ Symbols loaded.
    Windows.UI.Xaml.dll!00007ff85917e679()  Unknown No symbols loaded.
    Windows.UI.Xaml.dll!00007ff85917e2e8()  Unknown No symbols loaded.
    Windows.UI.Xaml.dll!00007ff85936c6b5()  Unknown No symbols loaded.
    twinapi.appcore.dll!00007ff8657d2b70()  Unknown No symbols loaded.
    twinapi.appcore.dll!00007ff8657d2ac3()  Unknown No symbols loaded.
    twinapi.appcore.dll!00007ff8657d2667()  Unknown No symbols loaded.
    rpcrt4.dll!00007ff86ea12713()   Unknown No symbols loaded.
    rpcrt4.dll!00007ff86ea7af0d()   Unknown No symbols loaded.
    rpcrt4.dll!00007ff86e9f3b92()   Unknown No symbols loaded.
    combase.dll!00007ff86d80b460()  Unknown No symbols loaded.
    rpcrt4.dll!00007ff86e9a9375()   Unknown No symbols loaded.
    combase.dll!00007ff86d7b6f5d()  Unknown No symbols loaded.
    combase.dll!00007ff86d7b6cf7()  Unknown No symbols loaded.
    combase.dll!00007ff86d81b6d8()  Unknown No symbols loaded.
    combase.dll!00007ff86d80578b()  Unknown No symbols loaded.
    combase.dll!00007ff86d8097c1()  Unknown No symbols loaded.
    combase.dll!00007ff86d8096bd()  Unknown No symbols loaded.
    combase.dll!00007ff86d7f14f1()  Unknown No symbols loaded.
    combase.dll!00007ff86d7ebaec()  Unknown No symbols loaded.
    combase.dll!00007ff86d78aab1()  Unknown No symbols loaded.
    combase.dll!00007ff86d78f97d()  Unknown No symbols loaded.
    combase.dll!00007ff86d78f360()  Unknown No symbols loaded.
    Windows.UI.dll!00007ff85bee7989()   Unknown No symbols loaded.
    Windows.UI.dll!00007ff85bee77e7()   Unknown No symbols loaded.
    twinapi.appcore.dll!00007ff86580fad6()  Unknown No symbols loaded.
    twinapi.appcore.dll!00007ff86580f9fc()  Unknown No symbols loaded.
    twinapi.appcore.dll!00007ff865838941()  Unknown No symbols loaded.
    SHCore.dll!00007ff86e6bbcad()   Unknown No symbols loaded.
    kernel32.dll!00007ff86e056ab0() Unknown No symbols loaded.
    ntdll.dll!00007ff86ebf1dbb()    Unknown No symbols loaded.
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Crash was because I was using `BodyStrongTextBlockStyle` and my app is not using `WinUI`. `BodyStrongTextBlockStyle` only exists if the app is using `WinUI` `2.6+`.